.Net Maui byte[] to Bitmap not working properly
I am using byte[] to Bitmap to print tickets on a printer in image form. However, the printed receipt shows only a line instead of the image.
Can anyone help where the code is wrong?

var img = ByteToImage(image);

public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.Length);
        return bm;
    }
}


//function to print 

public void PrintBitmap (Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap, ICallback callback)
{
    global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
 
    global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
 
    try {
        __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
        if (bitmap != null) { __data.WriteInt (1); bitmap.WriteToParcel (__data, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.None); } else __data.WriteInt (0);
        __data.WriteStrongBinder ((((callback != null)) ? (callback.AsBinder ()) : (null)));
        remote.Transact (IWoyouServiceStub.TransactionPrintBitmap, __data, __reply, 0);
        __reply.ReadException ();
 
    } finally {
        __data.Recycle ();
    }
 
}



What kind of printer is it?  How are you sending the image to the printer?  How large is the image?  What format?  You're assuming that the problem is with BitmapFactory when there are many other likely sources

Hello. it is an integrated thermal printer on a Sunmi POS. the printing width is 88mm. if i display the image on the screen, it is visible. it should be around 7cm x 15cm

i receive the image in base 64, i convert it to byte[] then create the bitmap and pass the bitmap to the printer.

Show the code that talks to the printer. I doubt you can use Bitmap directly there. Also, why is this marked with "maui"? System.Drawing.Bitmap is a WinForms type.

Hello please find the code below. it is from the library Woyou.Aidlservice.Jiuiv5
please find the code below on pastebin
https://pastebin.com/txZ0gevb

@PMF I am using .net maui

Please [edit] your question and include that snippet instead of using an external server. Are you running this on Android?

@PMF I edited the code snippet
